# SAS comparing two dates

Tags: date, sas, compare

I have a sas file which looks like

```
date1       date2       date3       comp

20201208    20110201    20120201  
20201208    20200101    20210201
```

all date are numeric with format `yymmddn8`. and `comp` is a text type.

Now I want to fill comp with 1 or 0 like

```
if date2 < date1 < date3 then comp=1; else comp=0;
```

but it doesn't work. I always get `1` even if the condition is true.

Progam (from comments)

```
data kl.kl_neukunde; 
  set kl.kl01; 
  format tday yymmddn8. ; 
  format date_nk yymmddn8. ; 
  format date_nk_12mon yymmddn8. ; 
  tday=today(); 
  date_nk = put(input(erste_besuch, ddmmyy10.), yymmdd8.)*1;
  date_nk_12mon = date_nk + 10000; 
  if date_nk='' then date_nk=0; 
  if date_nk_12mon='' then date_nk_12mon=0;
  if date_nk < tday < date_nk_12mon then neukunde="1";
```

Comment: I am unable to get the same results as you. The condition evaluates correctly for me. Can you post your full code in `datalines` format?

Comment: ```data kl.kl_neukunde;
set kl.kl01;
format tday yymmddn8. ;
format date_nk yymmddn8. ;
format date_nk_12mon yymmddn8. ;
tday=today();
date_nk = put(input(erste_besuch, ddmmyy10.), yymmdd8.)*1;
date_nk_12mon = date_nk + 10000;
if date_nk='' the date_nk=0;
if date_nk_12mon='' the date_nk_12mon=0;
if date_nk < tday < date_nk_12mon then neukunde="1";
```

Comment: Why are you adding 10,000 days to date_nk to create date_nk_12mon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to work with dates – you should learn how to use SAS dates as there are a lot of great functions that help with date handling.  What you are doing now is the hard way to work with dates.  A nice paper to learn about dates is: https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings/proceedings/sugi25/25/btu/25p058.pdf

For your specific SAS code you have two problems.

One problem is with variable `date_nk`.  The format used with the put function is missing an “n”.  The format `yymmdd8.` uses a dash to separate date parts so when that is multiplied by 1 to create a numeric variable the value becomes missing.  This will create a non-missing value:  `date_nk = put(input(erste_besuch, ddmmyy10.), yymmddn8.)*1;`

However, once `date_nk` is created like that, it is numeric but NOT a SAS date.  So the bigger problem is when you compare it with the `tday` variable which IS a SAS date.

See if this SAS code below makes sense:

```
data want;
  erste_besuch = '30-06-2020';

  format tday yymmddn8. ; 
  format date_nk yymmddn8. ; 
  format date_nk_12mon yymmddn8. ; 

  *** THIS IS A SAS DATE ***;
  tday=today(); 

  *** THESE ARE NUMERIC BUT -NOT- SAS DATES - SO USING DATE FORMATS WITH THESE VARIABLES IS A PROBLEM ***;
  *date_nk = put(input(erste_besuch, ddmmyy10.), yymmdd8.)*1;
  *date_nk = put(input(erste_besuch, ddmmyy10.), yymmddn8.)*1;
  *date_nk_12mon = date_nk + 10000; 

  *** THESE ARE SAS DATES ***;
  date_nk = input(erste_besuch, ddmmyy10.);
  date_nk_12mon = intnx('month', date_nk, 12, 'same');

  *** IF DATE VARIABLES ARE MISSING, KEEP AS MISSING, DO NOT RESET TO ZERO ***;
  *if date_nk='' then date_nk=0; 
  *if date_nk_12mon='' then date_nk_12mon=0;

  *** NOW YOU HAVE 3 VARIABLES THAT ARE ALL SAS DATES AND CAN COMPARE THEM CORRECTLY ***;
  if date_nk < tday < date_nk_12mon then neukunde="1"; 
run;

title 'NEW ATTEMPT';
proc print data=want;
run;
title2 'WITHOUT FORMATS';
proc print data=want;
    format _all_;
run;
```